# Python Extreme Slow iterrows

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm not a good coder in python and need help to change my iterrows function into some other stuff.

So -- I have two data frames, one is zips with lat & lng, another one is a bunch of locations with lat & lng. I need to map each zip with all the locations and calculate the distance between them.

**zip** Table:

```
|  zip  |  lat  |  lng   |
| 10001 | 40.81 | -73.04 |
| 10029 | 21.59 | -70.25 |
| 20033 | 30.21 | -52.11 |
| 30005 | 50.33 | -75.89 |
| 10203 | 40.23 | -30.21 |
```

**location** Table:

```
|location|location_lat|location_lng|
|    A   |    40.78   |   -74.44   |
|    B   |    38.69   |   -90.40   |
|    C   |    42.64   |   -73.78   |
```

Desired Output:

```
|  zip  |  lat  |  lng   | location |location_lat|location_lng| distance |
| 10001 | 40.81 | -73.04 |    A     |    40.78   |   -74.44   |   30000  |
| 10001 | 40.81 | -73.04 |    B     |    38.69   |   -90.40   |   32786  |
| 10001 | 40.81 | -73.04 |    C     |    42.64   |   -73.78   |   84637  |
| 10029 | 21.59 | -70.25 |    A     |    40.78   |   -74.44   |   75000  |
| 10029 | 21.59 | -70.25 |    B     |    38.69   |   -90.40   |   75319  |
| 10029 | 21.59 | -70.25 |    C     |    42.64   |   -73.78   |   87961  |
| 20033 | 30.21 | -52.11 |    A     |    40.78   |   -74.44   |   23810  |
| 20033 | 30.21 | -52.11 |    B     |    38.69   |   -90.40   |   56791  |
| 20033 | 30.21 | -52.11 |    C     |    42.64   |   -73.78   |   52000  |
| 30005 | 50.33 | -75.89 |    A     |    40.78   |   -74.44   |   63811  |
| 30005 | 50.33 | -75.89 |    B     |    38.69   |   -90.40   |   96731  |
| 30005 | 50.33 | -75.89 |    C     |    42.64   |   -73.78   |   75301  |
| 10203 | 40.23 | -30.21 |    A     |    40.78   |   -74.44   |   10348  |
| 10203 | 40.23 | -30.21 |    B     |    38.69   |   -90.40   |   89614  |
| 10203 | 40.23 | -30.21 |    C     |    42.64   |   -73.78   |   59310  |
```

The zip table has about 45k rows, and the location table has about 25k rows. And below is my code, which runs extremely slow. I'm wondering if there're any ways to re-factor my code so that it runs faster?

```
from geopy.distance import geodesic
mapped_data = []
for index, i in zip.iterrows():
    centre = [i['lat'], i['lng']]
    location.loc[:, 'distance'] = location .apply(lambda x: geodesic((x["location_lat"], x["location_lng"]), centre).meters, axis=1)
    if len(output) != 0:
        output.loc[:, 'zip'] = i[zip]
        output.loc[:, 'lat'] = i['lat']
        output.loc[:, 'lng'] = i['lng']
    mapped_data.append(output)

final_table = pd.concat(mapped_data)
```

Thanks!

Edit:
A cross join probably is faster, but, my tables are large. A cross join will get a 45k x 25k = 1B rows data set......

Comment: what is `geodesic`? (also I think you miss something on line 2 and 4)

Comment: you should try to run it without iterations. Maybe you should use `.join()`/`.merge()` or similar and later calculate distance (also without using iteration). OR maybe you should put it in database (ie. `SQLite`) and use SQL query with function `JOIN`

Comment: pandas doc: [Merge, join, concatenate and compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html). It may be faster to use `join` which uses C/C++ code.

Comment: maybe it will be larger but it may be still faster. You can try to run it partially - for few rows from `zip` create cross join and calculate distances and repeate it for next few rows. Maybe it will faster then your code and use less memory then my version. But your `final_table` should also the same size - `45_000 * 25_000 = 1_125_000_000` minus elements with `distance = 0`

Comment: Are you interested in the closest few? In that case, like k=10, there are faster implementations

Answer (score 1):

Using `for`-loop in pandas can be slow because it doesn't use C/C++ code.

I can't test it because I don't have `geodesic` so I can't check if `geodesic` doesn't make problem but first you could use pandas functions (C/C++ code) to create all rows (cartesian product for both dataframes), later use `apply` to calculate distances, and eventually later remove rows with `distance == 0`

```
result = zip_code.merge(location, how='cross')

result['distance'] = result.apply(lambda row: geodesic((row["location_lat"], row["location_lng"]), (row['lat'], row['lng'])).meters, axis=1)

result = result[ result['distance'] != 0 ]
```

---

Minimal working example.

It also measure time but I couldn't run original version (code from question seems useless) to compare time.

```
text1 = '''zip | lat | lng
10001 | 40.81 | -73.04
10029 | 21.59 | -70.25
20033 | 30.21 | -52.11
30005 | 50.33 | -75.89
10203 | 40.23 | -30.21'''

text2 = '''location | location_lat | location_lng
A   |    40.78   |   -74.44
B   |    38.69   |   -90.40
C   |    42.64   |   -73.78
'''

from geopy.distance import geodesic
import pandas as pd
import io
import time

zip_code = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text1), sep='\s*\|\s*', engine='python')
#print(zip_code)

location = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text2), sep='\s*\|\s*', engine='python')
#print(location)

# --- new version ---

start = time.time()

# cartesian product
result = zip_code.merge(location, how='cross')

# distance
result['distance'] = result.apply(lambda row: geodesic((row["location_lat"], row["location_lng"]), (row['lat'], row['lng'])).meters, axis=1)
#print(result)
#print('len:', len(result))

# remove zero distance
result = result[ result['distance'] != 0 ]
#print(result)
#print('len:', len(result))

end = time.time()
diff = (end-start)*1000
print(f'new version time: {diff:.2f} ms')
print(result)
```

Result with time:

```
new version time: 60.64 ms

      zip    lat    lng location  location_lat  location_lng      distance
0   10001  40.81 -73.04        A         40.78        -74.44  1.181992e+05
1   10001  40.81 -73.04        B         38.69        -90.40  1.503765e+06
2   10001  40.81 -73.04        C         42.64        -73.78  2.123733e+05
3   10029  21.59 -70.25        A         40.78        -74.44  2.164167e+06
4   10029  21.59 -70.25        B         38.69        -90.40  2.701184e+06
5   10029  21.59 -70.25        C         42.64        -73.78  2.357394e+06
6   20033  30.21 -52.11        A         40.78        -74.44  2.330939e+06
7   20033  30.21 -52.11        B         38.69        -90.40  3.613810e+06
8   20033  30.21 -52.11        C         42.64        -73.78  2.371461e+06
9   30005  50.33 -75.89        A         40.78        -74.44  1.067376e+06
10  30005  50.33 -75.89        B         38.69        -90.40  1.727085e+06
11  30005  50.33 -75.89        C         42.64        -73.78  8.699444e+05
12  10203  40.23 -30.21        A         40.78        -74.44  3.708925e+06
13  10203  40.23 -30.21        B         38.69        -90.40  5.080242e+06
14  10203  40.23 -30.21        C         42.64        -73.78  3.611013e+06
```